# ExpressJS backend Server with Angular2 CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, express, backend, angular-cli

I am using this Express Server to authenticate users by signing in by their steam account. 
everything works now as expected.
What i want to know now, is how i can integrate this to my Angular2 Project, so i can use in the HomeComponent a Login Button which calls the Express Server.
Is it better to work with an Server.js or with a Server.ts Backend Server?
and will it be visible ? if yes, where should be its destination to garantuee security ?

Im new to this, thats why im so curious :)

thanks in advance

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const FirebaseStore = require('connect-session-firebase')(session);
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const firebaseinit = firebase.initializeApp({
credential: ('**************************************'),
databaseURL: '**************************************'
});
// *************************************************************************************************************
var passport = require('passport'),
util = require('util'),
SteamStrategy = require('./').Strategy;
// *************************************************************************************************************
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
done(null, user);
});
// *************************************************************************************************************
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
done(null, obj);
});
// *************************************************************************************************************
passport.use(new SteamStrategy({
returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/steam/return',
realm: 'http://localhost:3000/',
apiKey: '**************************************'
},
function(identifier, profile, done) {
process.nextTick(function () {
  profile.identifier = identifier;
  return done(null, profile);
});
}
));
// *************************************************************************************************************
var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/signon/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(session({
store: new FirebaseStore({
  database: firebaseinit.database()
}),
secret: 'keyboard cat',
name: 'name of session id',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true
}));
// *************************************************************************************************************
// *************************************************************************************************************
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../public'));
// app.post('/auth/openid', passport.authenticate('openid'));
//                         *************************************************************************************************************
app.get('/auth/steam',
passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
function(req, res) {
res.redirect('/');
});
// *************************************************************************************************************
app.get('/auth/steam/return',
passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
function(req, res) {
res.redirect('/');

var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("/UserID");
var SteamUserID = ref.child(req.user.id);
SteamUserID.update({
          Username : req.user.displayName,
          UserImg : req.user.photos[2].value
      }); 
});

// *************************************************************************************************************
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
req.logout();
res.redirect('/');
});
// *************************************************************************************************************
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});
// *************************************************************************************************************
app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});
// *************************************************************************************************************
app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('listening on port 3000!')
})
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
res.redirect('/');
}
console.log('Listening on port ' + app.listen);
```

Comment: can really nobody help me with this?